# Что значит оповещение в Idea "This inspection reports all fields..."?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Idea В класс выделила в методах модификатор паблик и выдает замечание(не ошибку):
"This inspection reports all fields, methods or classes, found in specified inspection scope,that may have their access modifier narrowed down.." Объсяните пожалуйста, на что  IDE мне намекает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагает уменьшить уровень доступа для методов или полей. Например до protected  с public или до private с protected.